# Special signs and command line arguments

Tags: c

How to write code that shows error when user tries to start program with command line arguments that are special signs? My program works when user types only 1 or 0 and i know how to protect my program from beign run with other numbers but i dont know what to do with special signs.
By special signs I mean for example "$ #" etc. I tried to apply your solution but it still doesn't work. The problem is that when I run my program with "121" it works fine, it shows error "ERROR" but when it comes to running program with "1#" it just stops working and doesn't show "ERROR" 
C language

```
 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {
 FILE *in = argc > 1 ? fopen(argv[1], "r") : stdin;
 double x; 
  if (in != NULL){
     while (fscanf(in, "%lf", &x) == 1){
     if(x != 1 && x != 0){
        printf("ERORR");
        return 1;
   }
```

Comment: Start by showing us the code you're using now.  If you give a minimal, verifiable example you'll probably get an answer right away.  If a snippet that isn't complete, it depends on who reads and how clever they are.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: "Special signs" is rather unspecific; I suggest you'd clarify what you mean by that and perhaps give an example where you fail to handle such arguments. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what are "special signs". I'm assuming you refer to incorrect input, which will prevent the code from looking skipping over the bad tokens. Consider a different loop that will read tokens, and validate the input. Assuming each token is up to 20 characters.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdboolh>

static bool scan_int(FILE *fp, int *res_p) 
{
   bool first = true ;
   while ( 1 ) {
       int r = sscanf(work, " %d", res_) ;
       if ( r == 1 ) return true ;
       if ( r == EOF ) return false ;
       // print a message on first error
       if ( first ) { printf("ERROR\n") ; first = false ; };
       // try skipping a character ;
       getchar() ;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
     FILE *in = argc > 1 ? fopen(argv[1], "r") : stdin;
     if (in != NULL){
        int x ;
        while ( scan_int(in, &x) ) {
            if ( x != 0 ||  x != 1)) {
               printf("ERROR\n");
               return 1;
           } ;
         ...
         }
     }
}
```

From the post, looks like code should ignore non-digits (special symbols), but exit (return 1 from main), if the input value is not valid (0, 1). This logic is kept.

Comment: Your first OR (`||`) should be an AND (`&&`) and your parentheses are misplaced.

Comment: Thanks for checking. Hard to get things right while not seating in front of a desktop

Comment: By special signs I mean for example "$ #" etc. I tried to apply your solution but it still doesn't work. The problem is that when I run my program with "121" it works fine, it shows error "ERROR" but when it comes to running program with "1#" it just stops working and doesn't show "ERROR"

Comment: @Monika. With input of '#1' the above code will set x=1, and will continue runnng. Probably getting into infinite loop somewhere else. Looks like you want a function that will read an number (int/double), but will ignore non digits ("specials"). Suggesting editing the question to reflect this more clearly. Also, does the input comes on value at a line, or possible multiple values on a line ?